# Speed up C# / Selenium tests

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, nunit, selenium-webdriver

We use Selenium integrated with C# to do our web app testing.  The problem I've noticed is that compared to other Selenium + [code] combinations, Selenium + C# is *incredibly* slow.

This is just a simple "log into, then out of, our web app" test.

- 0:04 -- Selenium IDE within Firefox
- 0:05 -- Selenium WD + Python, test only
- 0:09 -- Selenium WD + Python, total run
- 0:11 -- Selenium WD + C# via Visual Studio > debug, test only
- 0:20 -- Selenium WD + C# via Visual Studio > debug, total run
- 0:25 -- Selenium WD + C# + NUnit, test only
- 0:35 -- Selenium WD + C# + NUnit, total run
- 0:37 -- Selenium WD + C# + NUnit through Jenkins, test only
- 0:56 -- Selenium WD + C# + NUnit through Jenkins, total run

What could I be looking at to make this less abominably slow?

Comment: Well what code are you running? I hope you've made this a very simple test to help prove the issue. Against what site? What versions of Selenium? What browser? What version of that browser? Have you enabled trace logs for the driver? Tried it on other machines? Are the pages slow to load or is Selenium slow in executing the commands? What's CPU & Memory usage like when this is going on?

Comment: I would recommend saving those times, and then adding another test, and then comparing the times.  I don't believe that the actual test is running any slower, just each part that you include adds to the initialization time (and possibly minor increase in time for the actual tests)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're running your tests on x64 system. If that is true, you should use x64 WebDriver.

Comment: was this a problem you personally experienced and the fix you found for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running .NET Core, you are hitting a known [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24104).

Switching to `127.0.0.1` both in IISExpress and in the test uri mitigates the issues.

You may have a look at [Selenium running very slowly (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950287/selenium-running-very-slowly-c/55106209#55106209).

Answer (score 0):

You can set an option on the ChromeDriver to speed up your tests.

```
 var options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("headless");
 var driver = new ChromeDriver("path", options);
```

> headless option run driver in background system and doesn't show GUI

this [link](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-headless-browser-testing/) give you more description about headless.

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of factors that come into play here, but from my experience c#+Selenium is one of the fastest I've used.

Here are a couple things you could try:

- If you're parrallelizing tests, lower the amount of tests that run at once. It really bottle necks performance and can sometimes mess with the test integrity.
- Code Cleanup. I was given a tool to test brute force logins and it could barely make the threshold (20 times in under X seconds). I re-arranged, re-used, re-centralized some functions and we were reaching the threshold in under 30 seconds. This also helped me get more parallelized tests running
- If you're running it over an RDC, check network performance, securities, etc.