# Selenium running very slowly (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm pulling my hair out about Selenium running slowly.

If I restart my PC and run my test for the first time it'll perform at the correct speed.

If I immediately rerun my test it takes forever! Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

It's not particularly complex code either, just entering data and clicking a couple of links. It only started doing this recently. Prior to about a week ago it would just run at the correct speed (ie.pretty rapid).

Versions of Selenium

```
Selenium.Webdriver - v3.6
Selenium.Support  - v3.6
Selenium.WEbdriver.IEDriver - 3.6 


var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
driver.FindElementByXPath(AddRecord).Click();

//Input date on Case details page 
driver.FindElementById(C4NameID).SendKeys(C4NameArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(EliteMatterX).SendKeys(EliteMatterRefArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(StatusX).SendKeys(StatusArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(PolicyCategoryX).SendKeys(PoliceCategoryArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(ScheduledDateX).SendKeys(ScheduledNextReviewDateArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(ServiceLineX).SendKeys(ServiceLineArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(BridgingPaymentX).SendKeys(BridgingPaymentArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(SubClusterX).SendKeys(SubClusterArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(DidWilliamsLeaHaveARoleX).SendKeys(DidWilliamLeaHaveARoleArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(C4TypeX).SendKeys(C4TypeArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(LegalOmbudsmanX).SendKeys(LegalOmbudsmanCategoryArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(FeeEarnerID).SendKeys(FeeEarnerNameArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(FeeEarnerPhoneNoID).SendKeys(FeeEarnerPhoneNumberArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(ContactPartnerID).SendKeys(ContactPartnerArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(C4OwnerID).SendKeys(C4OwnerArray[i]);

//Wait
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);


//Click INformation for Insurer tab 
driver.FindElementByXPath(InformationForInsurerTab).Click();
//Wait
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

//Inputs for Info for insurers page  
driver.FindElementById(C4OccurrenceDateID).SendKeys(C4OccurenceDateArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(IndemnityPeriodID).SendKeys(IndemnityPeriodArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(InsuranceReferenceID).SendKeys(InsurerRefArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(FEResponsibleWhenErrorOccuredID).SendKeys(FEResponsibleWhenErrorOccuredArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(C4HolderID).SendKeys(C4HolderArray[i]);

//Wait
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

//Click INformation for Insurer tab 
driver.FindElementByXPath(CaseDetailsTab).Click();
//Wait
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

/*//Inputs for Info for case details tab
driver.FindElementByXPath(BackgroundX).SendKeys(BackgroundArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(ResolutionPlanX).SendKeys(ResolutionPlanArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(LatestPositionX).SendKeys(LatestPositionArray[i]);
driver.FindElementByXPath(ConditionalLearningPointsX).SendKeys(ConditionalLearningArray[i]);
*/
//Wait
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

//Click Financials tab
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='c4wrapper']/form/div/ul/li[4]/a").Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
//Iouts for Financials tab
driver.FindElementById(MaxPossLossID).SendKeys(MaxPossLossArray[i]);
driver.FindElementById(ProbMaxLossID).SendKeys(ProbMaxLossArray[i]);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
//Click Save  

var SaveButton = driver.FindElementById(SaveX); 
SaveButton.Click();
```

Comment: Could you please give more details like version you are using and whether you have taken an update

Comment: Just added those in. I'm using versions 3.6 of selenium

Comment: If you use .Net core, this may be cause by the bug - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4988

Comment: I actually solved this by copying the IEdriver.exe file from another project into my project. Every now and again it seems Visual Studio redownloads the "new" selenium which is horrendously slow so I just go in and copy the fast IEdriver back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running .NET Core, you are hitting a known [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24104).

Switching to `127.0.0.1` both in IISExpress and in the test uri mitigates the issues.